# jQuery autocomplete that retrieves items from a database

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I want to provide autocomplete for users when they are filling in a text box. The values for the autocomplete should come from a mysql database that I use with the application. Can you please recommend a plugin or two that would be best suited to this.

I can see that there are a number of options out there. But I was hoping that based on the answers it would be clear that one or two plugins are considered to be the better ones, and I would only have to choose from those.

Thanks,

Comment: I believe writing such a plugin yourself would best fit your needs, since it's your database layout.

Answer (score 1):

I use jQueryJSONSuggestBox http://www.tomcoote.co.uk/jQueryJSONSuggestBox.aspx it works on keypress with json.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete works great.